# How to prevent initial onFocus trigger on TextField during first composition

Tags: focus, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, onfocus, onfocuschangelistener

Is there any way I can prevent `onFocus` trigger during the initial laying out of a composition?,

```
.onFocusChanged {
   // initial pass triggers un-necessary onFocus callback with just `false` values
   Log.e("TextFieldFocusChanged", "${it.isFocused} : ${it.hasFocus}")
 }
```

I have found this [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178510628) that seems related to such behavior, though the issue is not exactly related to an initial pass of a composition.

This thing can be solved by specifying some `boolean` flag depending on your needs, but handling it this way slowly introduces complex `boolean` evaluations depending on your use-case. Is there any way I can configure a `TextField` to prevent `onFocus` callback on initial pass?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you need to manage `boolean` flag for this.
Firstly, create a flag state, and set it to `true` on first composition:

```
var isInitialCompositionCompleted by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    isInitialCompositionCompleted = true
}
```

Secondly, use regular `onFocusChanged` modifier, and simply skip all callbacks until your flag is set to `true`:

```
Modifier.onFocusChanged { focusState ->
    if (!isInitialCompositionCompleted) return@onFocusChanged
    onFocusChanged(focusState.isFocused)
}
```

Here `onFocusChanged(focusState.isFocused)` is your outer lambda.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a more efficient way to handle this but the most optimal approach I can do for now is to rely on `SideEffect`.

```
@Composable
fun ScreenTextFields() {

     //..TextField ... onFocusChanged { onTextFieldFocus(it) }...
     //..TextField ... onFocusChanged { onTextFieldFocus(it) }...
     //..TextField ... onFocusChanged { onTextFieldFocus(it) }...
     //..TextField ... onFocusChanged { onTextFieldFocus(it) }...

     SideEffect {
         // notify and update a boolean state (e.g onFieldsPostComposition)
     }
}
```

and in a state class.

```
fun onTextFieldFocus(focusState: FocusState) {
     if (onFieldsPostComposition) {
         // do intended use-case on actual focus changes
     }
}
```

This way, any initial `onFocus` callback can be ignored/skip for your intended logic,  the only part I'm not sure if `onFocusChanged { ... }` callback is part of the `composition/re-composition`, not sure if there's a chance that `SideEffect` will occur **first** before `onFocus` callback, but so far, this approach works on my case..